# How to import javax.comm API to Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, ide

I am writing a program to read and write from and to serial port of a system using Java in Netbeans IDE. I am working with Ubuntu 14.04 operating system. Actually I am a beginner in java programming. I have downloaded comm-linux_all-2.0.0.jar from oracle's home site and it is copied to workspace directory.

After all these things I imported the API using the command

```
   import javax.comm.*;
```

But it shows the error "Package javax.comm does not exit."

What would be the problem, please help me to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

extract `comm-linux_all-2.0.0.jar` the files

somewhere in the NetBeans directory.

Here we take the following directory. (you know the path on ubuntu)

`\NetBeans80\extra\modules`

> RXTXcomm.jar
>   comm.jar

Now open `Netbeans : tools -> libraries`

- create a new lbrary `here : comm-linux_all-2.0.0`
- click `Add JAR/Folder`
- nav. to the folder where the files are.

[image]

- open the project -> Properties
- select `Libraries`
- click `Add Library ...`
- select the just created `comm-linux_all-2.0.0` Library

[image]

---

- copy `librxtxSerial.so` and `librxtxParallel.so` to `/usr/bin` folder.

now you can use.

```
import javax.comm.*;
....
public class JustaClass {
....
```

Comment: I copied the downloaded files to the netbeans installed directory and extracted them at /home/joshy/netbeans/. It generated the folder commapi, within that jar, lib, examples, docs folders were created, actually comm.jar was inside the jar folder. And it was added the libraries as you mentioned above. And in the case of rxtx library you mentioned to copy librxtxSerial.so and librxtxParallel.so to /usr/bin, I did that also, still it shows the same error. what should be wrong that I have done?

Comment: Not copy to `/home/joshy/netbeans`, copy to the **netbeans Application lib** folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the pom.xml file.
I had the same problem (I am a rookie)
I didn't add the dependencies :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```